# Android: make ImageButton's image larger

Tags: android, scale, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton:

[image: button]

I want to make the image (circular play image) bigger. I am aware of **android:scaleType**, but I don't want to stretch the image all the way to the borders of the button. I just want to make it a little bigger, say 120% of the current size.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your image in photoshope to make it bigger in your desire resolution.

Or

In android put height , weight of your image and set scaleType:FitCenter

Comment: I am not sure we are "on the same line" :)
What I have here in this ImageButton are two different elements - 
android:src="@drawable/stopwatch" &         android:background="@drawable/button_style"

I want to change only the size of the image (src) itself (the play circle) but not the whole button (the gray rectangle). Is this possible?
@user1134925

Comment: Actually your solution works. I've made the button larger in Photoshop and it works well. Thanks

Comment: That's great to here. :) it is best way to edit in Photoshope as in android if we change height , wight it will also change the background as per new size. But we can do that bay adding a background gradient xml in draw able. In that we can add padding to conners

Comment: In fact, it should be "fitCenter" instead of "FitCenter".

Answer (score 0):

In the xml layout set the width and height to be a larger amount of dip.